# Funcionalidad del return en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estudiando el paradigma funcional en JavaScript me encontré con este código:

```
var rooms = ["H1", "H2","H3"];

var newRooms = rooms.map(function(rm) {
if (rm == "H3"){ return "H4"; }
else { return rm; }
});
```

Los outputs:

```
newRooms; // ["H1","H2","H4"]
rooms; // ["H1","H2","H3"]
```

Por que el return sirve allí para reemplazar el `"H3"` por el `"H4"`, cual es su función exactamente, por que pensé que solo funcionaba para literalmente solo retornar algo de una función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la funcion map de array lo que hace es iterar sobre cada elemento de un arreglo y lo reemplaza por el return de la funcion callback:

Ejemplo: Imagina que tienes un arreglo de numeros y quieres cambiarlo por un arreglo de los mismos numeros pero por 2.

```js
var arrayOfNumber = [1,2,3,4];

var callbackFunction = function(number){
return number * 2;
}

var newArrayOfNumber = arrayOfNumber.map(callbackFunction);

// output [2,4,6,8]
console.log(newArrayOfNumber)
```

Ahi lo que hace el map es ejecutar la funcion callbackFunction en cada uno de los numeros y asigna en su posicion lo que retorna (numero * 2), claramente puedes jugar con numero y no solamente retornar numeros, sino tambien objetos, string, lo que quieras.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map):

> El método map() crea un nuevo array con los **resultados** de la llamada a la **función** indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos.

Este método ejecuta una misma función para cada elemento del array en que se aplica, se va ir añadiendo un elemento a un nuevo array según el resultado de ejecutar dicha función con cada elemento como parámetro.

> Por que el return sirve allí para reemplazar el "H3" por el "H4"

Veamos esta función

```
const cambio = (elemento) => {
    if (elemento === 3) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return elemento;
    }
};
```

Si el elemento que se usa como parámetro es 3, se cambiará por 5. Si no es el caso se conservará el mismo elemento. Con los condicionales se evalúa el elemento y dependiendo del elemento se retorna un valor u otro.

Podemos generar un nuevo array al que se aplique este cambio (de 3 a 5), de esta manera

```js
elementos = [1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,3];

const cambio = (elemento) => {
    if (elemento === 3) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return elemento;
    }
};

nuevos = [];
for (let i = 0;i < elementos.length;i++) {
    nuevos.push(cambio(elementos[i]));
}

console.log(nuevos);
```

Esto es un poco *largo*, entonces podemos hacer uso de `map()`. Como ya dije esta va aplicar la función que se use como parámetro sobre cada elemento y se va añadir el resultado de esta llamada al nuevo array que se genera.

```js
elementos = [1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,3];

const cambio = (elemento) => {
    if (elemento === 3) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return elemento;
    }
};

nuevos = elementos.map(cambio);
console.log(nuevos);
```

Esto es básicamente lo que pasa con el ejemplo que pones, si el elemento sobre el que es la iteración actual es `"H3"` se va a añadir `"H4"` al nuevo array generado, en otro caso se añade el mismo elemento (por eso es que se retorna el mismo elemento).

Con `map()` se puede usar cualquier tipo de función, solo tiene que quedar claro que **al nuevo array se va a añadir el valor retornado por la función que se use como parámetro.**

Answer (score 1):

El `return` sirve para retornar un valor una vez se termina de ejecutar una función.

Entonces el valor retorna justo en donde llamaste a la función, también por eso una invocación de función `doSomething()` es una expresión porque se evalúa a un valor, como si hicieras una suma o cualquier otro calculo.

Las funciones son objetos, un valor que puedes pasar como argumento, y ejecutarlo donde lo tengas.

Ahí pasas como argumento la función y dentro de map se ejecuta, puedes hacer lo mismo con tus propias funciones, pasarle como argumento otra función y ejecutarla.